# Evaporating water using water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat-engine

I found a problem in the problem-sheet for 8-graders and I am  curious how to solve it because I guess I have forgotten something important needed for this.

The problem: how much water at 373 K can one evaporate using 1 kg water at 273 K?

This problemsheet is on heat engine and the only tool there is in 8-th grade for this is $\frac{T_h-T_c}{T_h} = \frac{Q_h-Q_c}{Q_h}$.

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense to me... // "in 373 K" is a really weird way to state a temperature. Normally one would say "at 373 K".

Comment: Sorry I didn't learn physics in english, only math.

Comment: The problem still doesn't make any sense. If you have water at 373 K and some water at 273 K, and then you put them in contact what should happen is that the 373 K water will get colder and the 273 water will get warmer. The parameters of the problem have to detail how the "normal" exchange of heat is being circumvented.

Comment: 273 K is right at freezing, and 373 K is right at boiling. Maybe they're saying if you have a volume of water at 273 K, what volume would it have at 373 K?

Comment: I think we are supposed to use some kind of machine and the question about its restrictions